# Deserialize XML file to ObservableCollection and add object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, win-universal-app, xml-deserialization

I've used a button with this method to deserialize a ObservableCollection but after i can't no more add a object to my list.

```
private async void RecoveryList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("List.xml"); 
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<ProductClass>));

using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
   ObservableCollection<ProductClass> Products = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as ObservableCollection<ProductClass>;
   ListView1.ItemsSource = Products;
}
   }
```

And to serialize

```
private async void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<ProductClass>)); 
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("List.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); 

using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()) 
{
   serializer.WriteObject(stream, Products); 
   ListView1.ItemsSource = Products;
}
    }
```

To add product I've used this

```
private async void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
        Products.Add(new ProductClass{ Prodotti = TexBoxInputProducts.Text });           
  }
```

My ObservableCollection is

```
public ObservableCollection<ProductClass> Products;
```

My class is

```
namespace AppSpesaPhone.Models
{
   public class ProductClass
   {
        public string Prodotti { get; set; }
   }       
}
```

How can i add some "Product" to my list?

Comment: What is the exception you're getting?

Comment: When a user insert a product this one replace the entire deserialized list

Comment: I have a TextBox where the user insert a product, after the click on the add button, the product go in the list. So, when the user switch off the app i want that, when he came back, and after the click on "recover List", the app give him his old list. Now the user can add a product but if the list was deserialized the new product replaces the old deserialized list.

Comment: Nothing change, when i add a product nothing appear, only the deserialized list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a public `ObservableCollection<ProductClass>` field named `Products` in your class, but in your `RecoveryList_Click` method, you use a new `ObservableCollection` also named `Products` to retrieve the deserialized list and set it as ListView's `ItemsSource`. Although they are the same name, but they are not the same object. So you can't add new item to the ListView.

To fix this issue, you can remove the declaration of new `Products` in `RecoveryList_Click` method like following and make sure in all methods, you are operating the same object.

```
private async void RecoveryList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("List.xml");
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<ProductClass>));

    using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        Products = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as ObservableCollection<ProductClass>;
        ListView1.ItemsSource = Products;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Made my day!!